# Silverstripe & .htaccess - How to access a specific folder and view the directory index?

Tags: .htaccess, silverstripe

I want to be able to access the directory index view when I hit the URI `/client-files` - I am using Silverstripe which comes with its own `.htaccess` out of the box which I have provided at the end.

e.g `domain.com/client-files`

Sample image of what I am trying to achieve, just with a different folder name...

[image]

**I have tried the following:**

I have tried adding - (This gives me a 500 error):

```
<Directory "/client-files">
   Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

and adding this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` - This gives me "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /client-files/ on this server."

My **.htaccess** (Default)

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
# Deny access to templates (but allow from localhost)
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

# Deny access to IIS configuration
<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny access to YAML configuration files which might include sensitive information
<Files *.yml>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Route errors to static pages automatically generated by SilverStripe
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn off index.php handling requests to the homepage fixes issue in apache >=2.4
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/'


    # Deny access to potentially sensitive files and folders
    RewriteRule ^vendor(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule silverstripe-cache(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule composer\.(json|lock) - [F,L,NC]

    # Process through SilverStripe if no file with the requested name exists.
    # Pass through the original path as a query parameter, and retain the existing parameters.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]
</IfModule>

### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

Comment: What about having your own .htaccess in /client-files? Set RewritesEngine off and indexes on there?

Comment: Yip that seemed to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work by using what @munomono said but slightly different.

I ended up having my own .htaccess file in the `/client-files` directory and putting this in it:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: Glad to see you have solved your problem. Can you please mark your answer as the accepted answer so others know this questions is solved? Thanks.